# Other ways to specify a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, submanifold

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold. I am intersted in the different types of data I can use to specify a smooth submanifold $N\subseteq M$.

For example, if $f:M\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth map, then under some conditions on $f$ we can define $N=f^{-1}(0)$ with $\dim N=\dim M-n$.

Alternatively, if $N_0$ is a smooth manifold and $\varphi: N_0\to M$ is a smooth map, then under some conditions on $\varphi$ we can define $N=\varphi(N_0)$, with $N$ diffeomorphic to $N_0$.

Finally, we can use coordinate charts on $M$ in which $N$ lies along a canonical $\mathbb{R}^{\dim N}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{\dim M}$.

Are there any other general ways of specifying a submanifold? I'm mainly interested in local definitions. For example, defining a curve in $M$ as a flow line of a vector field from a given point isn't local because a local deformation of the vector field will lead to a global change in the curve.

Comment: The analogue of a curve being a flow line is an integrable distribution. In this context, a distribution consists of vector fields $X_1, \dots, X_k$ such that at each $p \in M$, the vector fields are linearly independent. The distribution is integrable if for each $1 \le i,j \le k$, $[X_i,X_j]$ lies in the span of $X_1, \dots, X_k$. The Frobenius theorem says that at each point $p$, there is a unique $k$-dimensional submanifold where the tangent space at each point is tangent to the vector fields. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)

Comment: Your third description is equivalent to the first (assuming you have the necessary rank condition in the first).

Comment: @Deane yep, but I didn't go there because that's exactly the kind of definition I don't want :)

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks for your comment. All these descriptions are equivalent.

Comment: Of course. I meant tautologically equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question to the end. But why isn't using vector fields local? If you change the vector fields on a subset of the manifold, it leaves the submanifold outside that subset unchanged.

Comment: @Deane, I don't think so. Think about changing lanes -- you change once but stay in the new lane forever. Or, if you change $f(x)$ near $x_0$, it will modify $\int^y dx f(x)$ for all $y>x_0$, unless your variation has vanishing integral.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk, that's not how I would define locality, and I don't think it's the standard mathematical definition. In any definition of a submanifold, if you modify the submanifold in a neighborhood of a point, you would always expect things to change in that neighborhood, including whether the point even lies on the original submanifold or not. For me, locality asks if you modify the submanifold in a neighborhood of a point, does it change the submanifold in a neighborhood of a point away from that neighborhood. For a vector field or an integrable distribution of them, the answer is no.

Comment: @Deane, If you consider a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\partial_x+f(x)\partial_y$, then the submanifold generated by it starting from point $(0,0)$ is defined by the equation $y-F(x)=0$, where $F(x)=\int_0^x dt f(t)$. Let us start with $f(x)=0$, then the manifold is given by $y=0$. Now make $f(x)$ a bump function in a small neighborhood of $x=1$ of total integral $\int dx f(x)=1$. Then after this local modification near $x=1$, the equation for large positive $x$ is $y=1$. Clearly, this is a non-local modification of the submanifold.